# See the code included in a php file on vscode

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, include, require-once

Is there a way to see the included code by "included" or "require_once" in the same file without open the included file? Sometimes I would like to have all the final code in the same page..
I usually use vscode, but if there is a way with another tool i can give it a try.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Dreamweaver has this capability: you can simply press Ctrl+D while cursor is on "include" or "require" and included file will open in the new tab. Very convinient. I have also searched for anything similar for VS Code, but sadly couldn't find anything. Adobe Dreamweaver is not free like VS Code though.